# Binary Operator + Cannot be Applied to Operands of Type CGfloat int

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, cgfloat

I am having the same problem as earlier with a different line of code; but this time, I wasn't able to fix it with the same approach as last time:

```
 var Y : Int = 0
 var X : Int = 0
 @IBOutlet var ball : UIImageView!
 ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x + X, ball.center.y + Y)
```

This is the error I am getting:

> binary operator + cannot be applied to operands of type CGfloat int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare them, instead, as the following:

```
let X : CGFloat = 0.0
let Y : CGFloat = 0.0
```

Replying to your comment:

The error has nothing to do with them being declared as `var` or `let`.
You could declare them as `var` and if you so insist on declaring them as `Int`, you would still need to do the following:

```
var X : Int = 0
var Y : Int = 0
ball.center = CGPointMake(view.center.x + CGFloat(X), view.center.y + CGFloat(Y))
```

Comment: X and Y are suppose to be Int I don't want to change it as a constant by saying let and making them a float

Comment: I meant it has to be mutable, but yeah now your answer works now thanks

Comment: I will it says I have to wait though

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not having the same variable types, for example you can't add bool and string.

Change it to CGFloat instead of int:

```
let X : CGFloat = 0.0
let Y : CGFloat = 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

ball.center.x is a CGFloat and X is an Int.  That's where the compiler is complaining.

Swift likes you to type cast numeric types (as if there wasn't a hierarchy in numeric domains) but you can avoid that by declaring X and Y as CGFloat instead of Int.

You could also get rid of the issue for good by defining the operator (that Swift should already have imho):

```
infix operator + {}

func +(left:CGFloat, right:Int) -> CGFloat
{ return left + CGFloat(right) } 

func +(left:Int, right:CGFloat) -> CGFloat
{ return CGFloat(left) + right }
```